# Surjectivity proof

Tags: functions

In my maths book a function is said to be surjective if the img(f) is the same as the codomain of f, does this hold if it fits inside the codomain rather then equal it? if so how would you write this mathematically, thanks in advance.

Comment: the image of $f$ is always a subset of the co-domain, the function $f$ is said to be surjective **only** if they are equal.

Comment: Are you aware of any function whose image *doesn't* fit inside the codomain?

Comment: Thanks for the help yanko

Answer (score 0):

We say that a function $ f : A \rightarrow B$ is surjective if and only if for every element $b \in B$ there exists an element $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = b$. Note that this definition implies that the image of $f$ **must** be equal to the codomain.